# How to get the list of online users in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I get the list online users in asp.net?
I use membership, and want to get list of online users.
I want to see who is online and who signed out.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
MembershipProvider.GetNumberOfUsersOnline
```

See these:

[Retrieve a List of Authenticated Users using ASP.NET, AJAX, and FormsAuthentication](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33233/Retrieve-a-List-of-Authenticated-Users-using-ASP-N)

[Online active users counter in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29792/Online-active-users-counter-in-ASP-NET)

[get a list of online users in asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774347/get-a-list-of-online-users-in-asp-net-mvc)

[ASP.NET see if member is online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708070/asp-net-see-if-member-is-online)

[ASP.NET | Forms Authentication | Get ALL logged in users(list of all users or count)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649868/asp-net-forms-authentication-get-all-logged-in-userslist-of-all-users-or-co)

Comment: salam. man mitonam email ya id az shoma dashte basham? ya jaee ke betonam soalamo azaton beporsam? chon hanoz nafahmidam chetori list karbarane online ro migirim

Answer (score 1):

asp.net Membership provider already have method that give you count of number of online users

```
MembershipProvider.GetNumberOfUsersOnline
```

[MembershipProvider.GetNumberOfUsersOnline Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.getnumberofusersonline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: OP asked for a method to get the list of online user, not how to count them.